# Fill values from a list with conditions -Excel

Tags: excel

I need to produce a formula, that can generate a list that follow to the below conditions,

- Each letter can only appear in the same column again once the every letter in the list has been used.
- If letter is in row 1 column 2 it can't be in row 2 column 1.
- The same letter can't be in both columns at the same time.

Example, 
List: A,B,C,D

Result,

```
    Column 1    Column2
Row 1   A          C
Row 2   B          D
        C          A
        D          B
        A          C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your list in column A

then put this in the first cell, copy over one and down as far as desired:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,MOD((ROW(1:1)-1)+(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*2,COUNTA($A:$A))+1)
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to apply this to two lists?

List 1 - ABCD 
List 2 - EFGH

List one can only be in column 1, list 2 can only be in column 2, both columns can t contain the same value, value in row 1 column 2 cant be the same as row2 column 1?

Comment: That is a new question.  Please create a new one.

Comment: I'm not able to at the moment, is there any chance i can edit this question or it can be answered as its linked to it?

Comment: Please do not change the question after getting an answer, as it will invalidate the answer and open the answer to down votes.  This is not a normal forum.  Each post is a unique question to which one would get answers.  Once answered it is done.  New Questions get new posts.  You will need to wait the time limit then ask a new question.  In the new question you can link to this one as a base.

Comment: Done as requested - Generate a list from two different lists meeting conditions -Excel